# Stem and leaf representation with an amplitude of 5

Tags: data-visualization

How do I go about representing data in a stem and leaf diagram with an amplitude of 5? Do I write the number modulus 5 or what? I find it confusing and not helping in organizing the data at all.

Comment: Edited tags. I can't see that this has anything to do with `graphical-model`.

Comment: @Nick Cox, Sorry, i had no idea abour the avaible tags, sorry for any misunderstanding caused.

Comment: No misunderstanding here. More importantly, a concrete example would be a good idea if answer(s) to date do not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean a bin or interval width of 5 (or ... 0.05 or 0.5 or 50 or ...)? It's hard to imagine a good implementation of stem and leaf that doesn't have some handle to tune bin width. Here trivially are

[image]

[image]

two such as reproduced according to simple ideas discussed in 
Cox, N.J. 2007. Speaking Stata: Turning over a new leaf. *Stata Journal*
7(3): 413-433. [.pdf here](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0028)

Stem-and-leaf was John W. Tukey's personal twist on a long-established kind of tallying display and the initial motivation included easy implementation by hand on any scrap of paper available. The first programs tended to be geared to typewriter or lineprinter output and so results seem rather clunky by modern standards. The recipe followed for the example above is just to draw a scatter plot. The vertical coordinate is usually a rounded version of the variable shown, the horizontal coordinate is rank order within bins, numeric characters are shown rather than marker or point symbols, and naturally rotation and reflection are allowed.

The data run 12, 12, 14, ..., 35, 35, 41.

Comment: Yes, i mean the interval width is 5, i know that in the cases of an interval width of 10,20 or 30, i write the numbers within an interval of 0-30, 30-60.. and so on, but with an interval of 5, it seems confusing to write numbers between 0-5, 5-10.. and so on.

Comment: I don't see what's confusing. Each value goes in precisely one bin, e.g. 0-4, 5-9, 10-14. As with histograms, and contrary to your comment, boundaries must not be ambiguously stated. Nothing stops you showing full values if they fit. See second example added above.

Comment: Oh, so for example, 15-19: 16,17, and so on, i dont have to only write the last digit i guess. Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/stemleaf2.htm , what about using the method used in this page, for example $0^{\{0\}}$ means 0-4.

Comment: Just a question of taste. Clarity comes first, but often just giving an example in the text caption is as good as a fussy notation invented for the purpose. In the first example, I might explain as follows: Bin width 5. Bottom row reads 12, 12, 14, etc; second row reads 15, etc.

Comment: I sure do find your representation more clear, but our proffesor tends to work by the book so i think he'd use the second notation., thanks for your help.